# Issues with upgrading to RSpec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to upgrade my project from rspec-rails 2.14 to the latest version. I'm following [these instructions](http://rspec.info/upgrading-from-rspec-2/).  I'm running into issues with installing RSpec 2.99.  After adding `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.99.0'` to my `Gemfile` and running `bundle install`, I see the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-core":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rspec-core (= 2.14.8)

  In Gemfile:
    guard-rspec (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rspec (< 4.0, >= 2.14) ruby depends on
        rspec-core (~> 2.14.0) ruby

    rspec-rails (~> 2.99.0) ruby depends on
      rspec-core (~> 2.99.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

How can I address this issue while affecting as few gem versions as possible?  I only want to update RSpec and nothing else.  If I run `bundle update` without any parameters it updates a bunch of other gems and makes a bunch of my tests fail.  Can I individually update dependent gems like `rspec-core` to a specific version somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  I only had `gem rspec-rails` in my Gemfile and had to add `gem 'rspec', '~> 2.99.0'`.  Running `bundle update rspec rspec-rails` then worked fine, and my `Gemfile.lock` shows the correct verison.